# iOS HTML5 date picker won't accept width: 100%;

Tags: ios, css, html, datepicker, mobile-safari

I have a html5 date picker in my form for a mobile version of my site. All my text inputs are set to width:100% and its parent td is set to padding-right:15px to make it fit. This means my fields are nicely formatted and adjust to always fill up half of the container when the orientation of the device changes. However the date picker does not behave in the same way, can anyone help?

Form:

```
<form method="get" action="home">
<table id="form">
<tr><td>
<input type="text" name="Title" class="tbox" placeholder="Title" />
</td><td>
<input type="text" name="Genre" class="tbox" placeholder="Genre" />
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="text" name="Location" class="tbox" placeholder="Location" />
</td><td>
<input type="date" name="Date" class="tbox" placeholder="DD/MM/YY" />
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="text" name="postcode" class="tbox" id="postcode" placeholder="Postcode" />
</td><td>
<input type="number" name="radius" class="tbox" placeholder="Mile Radius" /><br />
</td></tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.tbox {
background-color: #a1c9ff;
border: 1px solid #003f94;
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
margin: 3px 2px;
padding: 0 5px;
border-radius: 15px;
font-size: 18px;
float: left;
}

table#form tr td {
overflow: hidden;
padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
.tbox {  
    min-width:100%; 
}  
table#form {    
    width:100%;  
}
```

use width 100% for table#form and min-width:100% for .tbox, i hope this could solve your  problem. have updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/brfQf/1/

Comment: This works beautifully and should be the correct accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

This css style fixes the problem in mobile Safari:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

However, it changes input appearance.

Comment: 8 years later the problem is still there ... But nowadays you can use `appearance` without the prefix. Worth noting that you might want to style `::-webkit-date-and-time-value` afterwards (e.g. text in the input field is centered which looks odd).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like .tbox has both a width of 100% and a padding. This would result in the box extending outside of its desired area. To resolve this you could try adding `box-sizing: border-box;`

```
.tbox {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Whilst this did make my life easier with the text boxes, it doesn't fix my problem with the date picker

Comment: What is the date picker doing exactly that is not the desired effect? This is what it looks like when I put together a JSFiddle of it. http://jsfiddle.net/brfQf/

Comment: On that fiddle if you resize the output window to be thinner you'll see that the left half gets thinner whilst the right half stays the same size. This doesn't occur when the date picker is there. Also, on my phone, when I go into landscape it doesn't fill up the full size. In other words it seems to be ignoring width:100% and just being fixed around 100px.

Answer (score 0):

It is able to use a fixed value, So, you can use this unit to make it full screen:

```
width: 100vw
```

But you need to consider its compatibility, Here is a link about its compatibility:

http://caniuse.com/#search=vw